# How to remove "look up, translate, search web" options and keep "Find selection" for selected text iOS 16

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextview, ios16, xcode14

Working with UITextView

```
//...
txtView.isFindInteractionEnabled = true
//...
```

My code:

```
override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        builder.remove(menu: .lookup)
    }
    super.buildMenu(with: builder)
}
```

This will remove: Find selection, look up, translate, search web.

I want to keep only the option: **"Find selection"** and remove the others "look up, translate, search web"

Answer (score 0):

```
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        
        if action.description == "_findSelected:" {
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: It does not work. All options still appear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the whole menu you can remove specific child elements from it.

```swift
override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        builder.replaceChildren(ofMenu: .lookup) { elements in
            return elements.filter { item in
                switch (item as? UICommand)?.action.description {
                case "_define:", "_translate:":
                    return false
                default:
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    super.buildMenu(with: builder)
}
```

`_define:` action contains both the elements *Look up* and *Search web*.